# Send reminder email automaticaly with laravel task scheduler through hosting server

Tags: php, laravel, task, scheduler

I would like to send a reminder email to suppliers whose receipt date expires in 3 days.

So I created an `email:send` command in which I put my verification code and then sent the email. Then in the file `command/kernel.php` I execute my command `email:send` every minute.

email:commande logic

```
$data = $this->mailRep->getCommandes();
$current_date = Carbon::now();
$current_date = $current_date->addDays(3);
$current_date = $current_date->toDateString(); 
$mail_directrice = "souley27souley@gmail.com";

foreach($data as $commande ){
        if($commande->available_date === $current_date){
            $com = array("date" => $commande->available_date,"fournisseur" => $commande->fournisseur);

            Mail::to($commande->responsableEmail)
                ->cc([$commande->responsableEmail,$mail_directrice])
                ->send(new reminderMail($com,'Available'));
        } elseif ($commande->start_send_date === $current_date) {

            $com = array("date" => $commande->start_send_date,"fournisseur" => $commande->fournisseur);

            Mail::to($commande->responsableEmail)
                ->cc([$commande->responsableEmail,$mail_directrice])
                ->send(new reminderMail($com,'start send'));
        } elseif ($commande->arrive_at_port_date === $current_date) {

            $com = array("date" => $commande->arrive_at_port_date,"fournisseur" => $commande->fournisseur);

            Mail::to($commande->fournisseurEmail)
                ->cc([$commande->responsableEmail,$mail_directrice])
                ->send(new reminderMail($com,'Arrive au port'));
        } elseif ($commande->arrive_at_ouaga_date === $current_date) {

            $com = array("date" => $commande->arrive_at_ouaga_date,"fournisseur" => $commande->fournisseur);

            Mail::to($commande->responsableEmail)
                ->cc([$commande->responsableEmail,$mail_directrice])
                ->send(new reminderMail($com,'Arrive a ouaga'));
        } else {
            $this->info("No mail to send !");
        }
    }
```

reminderEmail class:

```
class reminderMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $viewData;
public $type;
public $mails;
public function __construct($datas,$type)
{
    $this->viewData = $datas;
    $this->type = $type;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from("info@groupekyba.com","PPI/Trakng-control")
        ->with(['commandes' =>$this->viewData, 'type' => $this->type])
        ->view('emails.emails');
}
}
```

command/kernel.php content

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\SendEmails::class
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('email:send --force')
              ->everyMinute();
}

/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

When I execute the command manually in the windows command prompt, everything goes well. The mails are sent. Now I've uploaded my project to hostinger where I created a cron job that runs my order per minute. However, the cron job runs normally, but the mails are not sent.

Comment: Do you use any form of queue? If so, remember that the likes of Horizon or supervisorctl may need to be restarted to pick up the changes to your code.

Comment: Thank you  Petay87 for your answer. I do not know if I understand your question, but I have actually made an implementation of ShouldQueue on my reminderMail class, does this pose a problem in the execution of my task?
really sorry!! Thanks again for your reply

Comment: Yes, I think it will as this informs laravel that the job should queue. This means that the app will be sending the job so a queue (Default will be set in you .env file).  If you have access try running php artisan queue:work and see if they run. If you don't want them to queue then you need to remove the queue instruction https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: I removed the implementation of ShouldQueue, but it's always the same.

Comment: Just to be clear, running php artisan email:send works from the command line?

Comment: yes, it's work perfectly.